# Is there any way to map many language codes to a single language code so that i can translate in a single file?

Tags: angularjs, locale, angular-translate

```
'en-*':'en_US',
'es-*':'es_ES', 
'pt-*':'pt_PT',
'fr-*':'fr_FR',
'de-*':'de_DE',
'ja-*':'ja_JP',
'it-*':'it_IT',
'*':'en_US'
```

Is there any way to map `en-*` into `en_US`? I may get any browser locale like `en-us`, `en-au` etc. So I need to map to this file `en_US`. If anyone knows please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is your friend :)

```js
var possible = [
  'en-us',
  'en-au',
  'fr-sb',
  'de-le',
  'it-nx'
]; // add to test

var locale = possible[Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length)];

var routes = {
  'en-*':'en_US',
  'fr-*':'fr_FR',
  'de-*':'de_DE',
  '*':'en_US'
};

var match = (route) => new RegExp('^' + route.replace('*', '.*')).test(locale)
var route = Object.keys(routes).find(match);

console.log(locale, 'routed to', routes[route]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It helped me!

Comment: Is there any replacement for 'find' in this code? It is not working in IE

Comment: You can find a polyfill here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find